# Get Data from Mysql in a modal Bootstrap 4.5 working w/ PHP and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I was inspired by the following source code:
https://github.com/felixivance/Bootstrap-Modal-with-Dynamic-MySQL-Data-using-Ajax-PHP

based on bootstrap 3.3.7 & jquery 3.2.1

My goal is to be able to use it with BTS 4.5 / jquery 3.5.1

Here is my code on the index page

```
<!-- get list --> 
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $row['beatid']."&nbsp;".$row['beatname']; ?></td>
 <td>
 <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showBeat" data-id="<?php echo $row['beatid']; ?>" id="getBeat" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> View</button>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the Modal code :

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="showBeat" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered"> 
   <div class="modal-content"> 
                  
   <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Your Listening</h4> 
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
   </div> 
   <div class="modal-body"> 
                       
    <div id="modal-loader" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
    <img src="ajax-loader.gif">
   </div>                            
  <!-- content will be load here -->                          
   <div id="dynamic-content"></div>                             
   </div> 
   <div class="modal-footer"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" datadismiss="modal">Close</button>  
        </div>            
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
```

My  JS/jquery code  :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(document).on('click', '#getBeat', function(e){
        var uid = $(this).data('id');   // it will get id of clicked row
        
        $('#dynamic-content').html(''); // leave it blank before ajax call
        $('#modal-loader').show();      // load ajax loader
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getData.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'id='+uid,
            dataType: 'html',

            success: function(data){
                $('#dynamic-content').html('');    
                $('#dynamic-content').html(data); // load response 
                $('#modal-loader').hide();
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#dynamic-content').html('Something went wrong, Please try again...');
                $('#modal-loader').hide();
            }
        })
        
    });
    
});

</script>
```

And my PHP code dealing with the $ .ajax request :

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    
    $connect = new PDO ("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dataname;charset=utf8", $user, $mdp);
    $connect -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $getBeat = $connect -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM databasename WHERE dataid=$id");
    $getBeat -> execute();
    $rows=$getBeat->fetch();            
?>          
        
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12"><img src="<?php echo $rows['data']; ?>" class="rounded mx-auto d-block"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3" style="margin:5px;text-align: center;">
        <audio src="../file/<?php echo $rows['data']; ?>" controls></audio>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

When I click on my link the modal opens well, but it gets stuck on the loader image

But it does not display the data coming from the database!

I tried to adapt the base code with whatever information I found, but nothing helped.

Could you tell me where my error (s) is, thank you in advance

Comment: You need to debug your code, open network tab in your browser (F12 for Chrome) then click the button you will see that request status.  Click that request and investigate what is going on there. Better dump your $_GET request to see what is in there.

Comment: And you should use  POST request for that. If you still insist on $_GET request  change ` url: 'getData.php'` as ` url: 'getData.php?uid='+uid`

Comment: Okay, when check the 'console tab' it is indicated > Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Comment: Did you add Jquery script into your souce code?

Comment: Yes the code link is added

Comment: Apparently the problem was with the jquery file.

I was using the simplified version, I changed it to the minified version and obviously that fixes the problem